# PyQt5 connect signals method

Tags: python, autocomplete, pycharm, pyqt5

I'm confused with the signals connections with pyqt5. My signals are working I'm just trying to understand the inheritance.

My imports are:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
```

Then I have a button

```
self.button_send_mail = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Resend', self)
self.button_send_mail.clicked.connect(self.button_send_mail_pressed)
```

If I open QPushButton.py there's no defined method "clicked". From Qt Docs I read that QPushButton inherits from QAbstractButton. I open QAbstractButton.py and there's the method clicked, but why my ide (pycharm 2017 with the pyqt5 modules installed) doesn't list the "clicked" method after I write self.button_send_mail.c...??

And the same happens for .connect but in this case, I have the warning: "cannot find the reference "connect" in function.

So, it works but I'd like to understand better, is it maybe because pyqt is wrapping  C functions? and pycharm cannot access to them?

Thanks

Comment: So your problem is actually code completion with PyCharm and PyQt5. You might get some answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205918/pycharm-pyqt5-and-python-2-7-no-code-completion. If not you should rephrase and retag your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, its related to. Sames as the same problem.